# What really determines punching force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, collision, power

When it’s $F=ma$ why do some fighter like Francis Ngannou has the hardest punch although there are other fighters at same weight with more velocity. Does muscle strength has something to do with that?

1. I think there are many types of punching force like breaking-power knockdown-power. Someone told me the higher the energy(velocity) the more chances to break it and cause injury. But if you put more velocity into the punch it will rather knock your opponent down instead of breaking.

PS: I’m a professional fighter and want to know how to get the breaking power.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/781448/2451

Answer (score 0):

As far as the physics is concerned, the real damage is caused by the impulsive force during the collision. If you deliver a punch with a huge velocity and the impact lasts for a short period of time, you inflict greater damage to your opponent.

### This is because:

If $\Delta v$ (change in velocity) is larger and $\Delta t$ (time-interval during punch) is small, $a$(acceleration) is large which produces a larger force, using the same relation $F=ma$ as you mentioned.

**PS:** *Pls don't break anyone!*

Comment: so u mean pulling the punch back right after impact as fast as possible? This is what gives me the "breaking power“?

Comment: If you apply too much force in withdrawing the punch, it will have the opposite effect. Because now, you are decreasing its momentum( to a large extent).

Comment: I don’t think so cause if the impact last longer the damage will deliver to other areas which got it’s pace(knockout) but if pull the punch back right after impact the damage will focus on the area where I hit and it breaks(breaking power)

Answer (score -1):

as a Kinesiologist my non physicist take on this question relates to the neuromuscular connections that contribute to power. The question is of efficiency of force generation rather than force as an expression of MxA.

Capacity for motor unit recruitment governs the ability for a person to produce 100% muscle activation and is a component of genetic and body composition factors (ie the bodies % make up of fast/short twitch muscle fibres is related to race, gender, and height and somatotype affect capacity for trainable results). These factors contribute to the potential summation of power that stem from the greatest possible recruitment of motor units throughout the body.

Taking a stab at the physics side of this answer, the vector quantity of the punch is related to the transfer of angular velocity - angular as the action of punching is a unilateral movement, performed on the transverse plane around the vertical axis of the body.